# How to add data in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem is in my current `code` it doesn't work

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/4GP2h/50/

Comment: Don't you want to bind to the `unload` event for the document?

Comment: @Anthony what do you mean about bind to the unload? sorry but im just a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things going on here:

- You've multiple elements with `id` gender, making your html invalid.
- [You can't store an array directly into `localStorage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage) you need to [stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it before inserting and [parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it after retrieving.
- The `localStorage.setItem()` function takes two parameters, the name (*key*) of the data to be stored and the actual data (*value*)

You're calling it with single parameter, like

```
localStorage.setItem(data) //Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.
```

Which should be something like `localStorage.setItem('info',data)`.

So that you can access the data upon page load using `localStorage.getItem()` like  `localStorage.setItem('info')`.

(*I had no previous experience with [datatables](http://datatables.net/), So i went through the [examples](http://datatables.net/examples/index) and [API](http://datatables.net/examples/api/) documentation*)

Once you have the data, you need to specify the [data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/data) and [columns](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns) options while initializing the table (*this [example](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) demonstrates how to initialize dataTable with data from a js source.*) as follows:

```
$('#myTable').dataTable({
  "data": dataSet,
    "columns": [{
    "title": "Name"
  }, {
    "title": "Age"
  }, {
    "title": "Gender"
  }, {
    "title": "Action"
  }]

// rest of the options
});
```

As you can see in the documentation, the [data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/data) option accepts a `2D` array; So instead of saving a single record in an array, you've to create an array of arrays of all the records and save it in `localStorage`

The fiddle below lets you save one record (*I'm wrapping it in another array for now*) in `localStorage`, retrieve and display it next time you visit.

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP2h/51/)

As mentioned by [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49478/anthony) in comments, it's better to save it once in [unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onunload) event rather than trying to update `localStorage` every time a record is created.

Comment: i found a bug in ur code it only store 1 row. If i add 2 rows and refresh the page it only store the last row i added. Can u fix it?

Comment: i want to store all the current contents of the table before it the browser was refresh or closed.

Comment: @user3817023 it's not a bug, that's what i mentioned in answer that you've to create an array of arrays; i fixed the problems in your code and gave you something to build upon (*i'm new to datatable than you are and actually spent few hours reading documentation and fiddling until the power gone*) it's easy to do the rest... don't expect copy pastable answers, those won't do you any good in long term since you won't learn anything. The reason i left all those links and explained how i got till here  is because somebody will learn something and know how to get to a solution next time... :)

Comment: im confused with your code why you make another variable called data? in my code i created a var data in save function already and you declare a variable data again?

Comment: @user3817023 javascript has function level scope. the one in your function is inside that functions scope, so that's not a problem. I used the same name for better understanding that we're getting the same data on load which we saved previously. Even if it's the same variable what's the problem..? at page load we can use it to store data from localStorage and afterwards we can use it to store data saved by user... What's the problem with it..? i don't understand your confusion.